# Is !temp->left and temp->left!=NULL different?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am learning about binary trees in c++ and during my practice I have many a time replaced

### **temp->left!=NULL** with **!temp->left**

however, in some cases, this gives an error are their meaning different?

For example here is a code to find the cousins in a binary tree in c++

```
vector<int> Solution::solve(TreeNode* A, int B) {
   queue<pair<TreeNode *,int>> q;
   q.push({A,0});
   vector<int> ans;
   int reqdepth=-1;
   int depth;
   while(!q.empty()){
       TreeNode *temp=q.front().first;
       depth=q.front().second;
       if(depth==reqdepth) break;
       q.pop();

      /* LOOK HERE */ if(temp->left!=NULL && temp->left->val==B || temp->right!=NULL && temp->right->val==B){ /*LOOK HERE */
           reqdepth=depth+1;
           continue;
       }
       else {
           if(temp->left) q.push({temp->left,depth+1});
           if(temp->right) q.push({temp->right,depth+1});
       }
   }
   while(!q.empty()){
       ans.push_back(q.front().first->val);
       q.pop();
   }
   return ans;
   
}
```

In this code the line bolded if changed doesn't give the correct solution even though it complies.
Please let me know if these notations are different and if so then how?

Comment: `temp->left != NULL` is equivalent to `temp->left` (no negation).

Comment: Yes, those two things are different... opposite in fact.  `if (!temp->left)` evaluates to `true` when `temp->left` is **zero** (or `nullptr`).  `if (temp->left)` evaluates to `true` when `temp->left` is non-zero.  Which is the same as the explicit `if (temp->left != NULL)`, although with modern C++ the style would be `if (temp->left != nullptr)`.

Answer (score 1):

`temp->left!=NULL` should be replaced with `temp->left` and not with `!temp->left`. The following should do the trick:

```
if(temp->left && temp->left->val==B || temp->right && temp->right->val==B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-null pointers convert to `true`, null pointers to `false`.

So `temp->left` converted to a boolean is the same as `temp->left != NULL`.
If you negate that you find that `!temp->left` is the same as `temp->left == NULL`.

In other words, the truth is the opposite of what you believed.

Answer (score 0):

temp->left!=NULL is true if temp->left is NOT NULL

!temp->left is true if temp->left is NULL

Comment: This makes sense! Now I get it! Thank you so much.